# Wordpress Queue like Tumblr?

Tags: posts, tumblr

Is there a way to give Wordpress the queue functionality that Tumblr has?  Tumblr's queue, for those who don't know, is a way to space posts out without assigning specific post dates.  For example, a Tumblr queue might be set to post every four hours between 9am and 5pm.  Tumblr would drop the front post in the queue at 9am, 1pm and 5pm every day.  Posts are added to the queue by clicking "add to queue" instead of "publish." It's quite simple.

How can this feature be added to Wordpress?

Comment: I just released this plugin to have a very simple way of auto-queueing posts: http://wordpress.org/plugins/queue-posts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Time Release](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/time-release/) plugin comes close, but has a fixed update period. The functionality is there, though, and I'd guess the portion of code that does the checking/updating could be hacked to use whatever (still-fixed) frequency you want without too much trouble.

**EDIT 2.16.12** Found a couple others that come much closer to Tumblr's behavior while working on something recently.

[Automatic Post Scheduler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/automatic-post-scheduler/) provides a simple setup where you specify a minimum and maximum interval between items. When something comes up for publishing, the system checks against the intervals and automatically pushes its scheduled time to the next available slot.

[Auto Schedule Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-schedule-posts/) has a much more robust set of options, allowing you to actually replicate the sort of "every # hours between x and y times" queuing that Tumblr does. It can also be limited to only post on certain days and so some randomizing.

Comment: Perfect. They should use the word "queue" in their description so Google can find it. :)